# php preg_replace remove number started string and execption

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have three situations, where I need to remove numbers characters.

**STRING200**, after preg_replace I expect **`STRING`**
**STRING 100 TEST**, after preg_replace I expect **`STRING 100 TEST`**
**STRING 400**, after preg_replace I expect **`STRING 400`**

I have tested the following combinations using preg_replace in PHP

`/^(?:[0-9]+\s)*/`
`/[0-9]*$/`
`/^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*$`

But without success, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: before/after 'string 100 test' and 'string 400' are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match 1+ digits after a letter until a word boundary and remove them:

```
preg_replace('~[a-zA-Z]\K\d+\b~', '', $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5BHhJg/1).

Or if you need to match the whole string (see [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/5BHhJg/2)):

```
preg_replace('~^[a-zA-Z]+\K\d+$~', '', $s)
```

**Pattern details**:

- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `\K` - match reset operator omitting the matched letter from the match value
- `\d+\b` - 1 or more digits followed by the end of word boundary.

**NOTE**: If the match is expected at the end of the string, replace `\b` with `$` (end of string anchor).

A [PHP test](http://ideone.com/0DxAnS):

```
$arr = ['STRING200','STRING 100 TEST','STRING 400'];
foreach ($arr as $s) {
   echo preg_replace('~[a-zA-Z]\K\d+\b~', '', $s) . PHP_EOL;    
}
// => [ STRING, STRING 100 TEST, STRING 400 ]
```